# change position bootstrap-wysihtml5

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

**How to** change wysihtml5-toolbar possition to bottom
[enter link description here](https://i.gyazo.com/246f96c0cdc7217f431cb73d317b1399.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `style.css` file add position to `.wysihtml5-toolbar` class:

```
.wysihtml5-toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```